# Is Doctor Fate a medical doctor?

Tags: dc, doctor-fate

Kent Nelson is known as Doctor Fate. Is he really a medical doctor like Dr. Strange or does he hold another PhD title?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J8rBDOMLtSU

Answer (score 17, accepted):

While "Doctor Fate" as a role that is passed down to various people is not necessarily a medical doctor in all of his incarnations, [Kent Nelson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Fate#Kent_Nelson), the first (published) Doctor Fate, was a physician in his original appearances in More Fun Comics, as you can see here:

[image]

> A holdup! And I think I recognize an old enemy! Looks like Dr. Fate will have to write a prescription with a punch!

Comment: That comic page is so delightfully cheesy.

Answer (score 10):

Harley Quinn certainly didn't think so for one of them:

> Wow, that’s some positive talk in front of the patient. Don’t worry, random little girl. I’ve never lost a monkey before and I’m not about to start today! And you! You can’t just put on a helmet and a cape and call yourself doctor. Some of us went to medical school and earned our title. Now, please take this small girl out of my operating room, Mister Fate.

https://comicnewbies.com/2014/10/29/harley-quinn-scolds-doctor-fate/

[image]

Comment: He could be a consultant... still a Dr but referred to as Mr?